# About invoke macro inside module

Tags: elixir

```
defmodule DemoMacro do
  defmacro i_am_macro do
    quote do
      # ……
    end
  end

  i_am_macro # (CompileError) example.exs:10: undefined function i_am_macro/0
end
```

But imported from other modules, can be successfully called:

```
defmodule SecondModule do
  require DemoMacro
  DemoMacro.i_am_macro
end
```

What should I do to make the first piece of code compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the macro *from the module body*, meaning *during the compilation stage*. On the compiler stage, this module content is obviously not accessible yet because the module is not compiled.

Move macro into a function:

```rb
defmodule DemoMacro do
  defmacro i_am_macro do
    quote do
      IO.puts "Inside a macro"
    end
  end

  def test_macro(), do: i_am_macro()
end

DemoMacro.test_macro()
#⇒ "Inside a macro"
```

Macro content is an AST that is being injected inplace on each macro call. During the compilation stage, you might use *already compiled* Elixir code. Understanding the difference between compilation stage and runtime requires kinda mental shift, mostly because in both stages we use same Elixir syntax. But the thing is Elixir, being a compiled language, cannot use the code unless it’s compiled into BEAMs.

---

You also can use your macro inside [`@after_compile`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-after_compile) callback, during compilation stage, immediately after the module BEAM becomes available (compiled):

```rb
defmodule DemoMacro do
  defmacro i_am_macro do
    quote do
      IO.puts "Inside a macro"
    end
  end

  @after_compile __MODULE__

  def __after_compile__(env, _bytecode) do
    i_am_macro()
  end
end
#⇒ immediately prints "Inside a macro"
```